# Custom ChangeMonitor for .Net MemoryCache causes invalid operation exception

Tags: c#, .net, invalidoperationexception

I have written my own custom change monitor class for the .NET MemoryCache. It seems to initialize fine, but when I attempt to add it to the Cache, it throws an `InvalidOperation` exception - `The method has already been invoked, and can only be invoked once.`

My change monitor class:

```
internal class MyChangeMonitor : ChangeMonitor
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private readonly string _uniqueId;
    private readonly TypeAsOf _typeAsOf;
    private readonly string _tableName;

    public GprsChangeMonitor(TypeAsOf typeAsOf, string tableName)
    {
        bool initComplete = false;
        try
        {
            _typeAsOf = typeAsOf;
            _tableName = tableName;

            _uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0, 0);
            _timer = new Timer {Interval = ts.TotalMilliseconds};
            _timer.Elapsed += CheckForChanges;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Start();
            initComplete = true;
        }
        finally 
        {
            base.InitializationComplete();
            if(!initComplete)
                Dispose(true);
        }
    }

    void CheckForChanges(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //check for changes, if different
        base.OnChanged(_typeAsOf);
    }
 }
```

The code I use to create the cache policy and add the key/value pair to the cache:

```
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy
{
    UpdateCallback = OnCacheEntryUpdateCallback
};

policy.AbsoluteExpiration = SystemTime.Today.AddHours(24);
//monitor the for changes
string tableName = QuickRefreshItems[type];
MyChangeMonitor cm = new MyChangeMonitor(typeAsOf, tableName);
policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(cm);
cm.NotifyOnChanged(OnRefreshQuickLoadCacheItems);

MyCache.Set(cacheKey, value, policy);
```

The `Set` call throws the invalid operation exception which is weird because, according to the MSDN documentation, it only throws the `ArgumentNull`, `Argument`, `ArgumentOutOfRange`, and `NotSupported` exceptions.

I am sure that I must be making a simple mistake. But it's hard to find good documentation or examples on writing your own custom change monitor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger, turn off Just My Code and then break on exceptions to see what the call stack is for the InvalidOperationException?

Comment: The stack trace is not very helpful. It is in System.Runtime.Caching.ChangeMonitor.NotifyOnChanged(OnChangedCallback onChangedCallback), but it was not in my callback for NotifyOnChanged, because it isn't being called.

Comment: Apparently, I have to add the change monitor to the policy AFTER I add the item to the cache. If I add it before, then I get the exception.

Comment: @Keith Please mark this as the answer.  I got stuck for way too long before reading this.  Thanks!

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest the opposite: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.changemonitors.aspx

Comment: Keith, 
>>Apparently, I have to add the change monitor to the policy AFTER I add the item to the cache<<
- In this case ChangeMonitor will not fire change event notification - just tested it.

Answer (score 6):

*I know the comments have the answer, but I wanted it to be more obvious...*

When a `ChangeMonitor` is used,  it will fire immediately if the cache entry does not exist.
MSDN [documentation states it this way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.createcacheentrychangemonitor.aspx):

> A monitored **entry is considered to have changed** for any of the
>   following reasons:
>
> A) The **key does not exist at the time of the call** to the 
>    CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor method. In that case, the resulting
>    CacheEntryChangeMonitor instance is immediately set to a changed
>    state. This means that when code subsequently binds a
>     change-notification callback, **the callback is triggered immediately**.
>
> B) The associated cache entry was removed from the cache. This can 
>     occur if the entry is explicitly removed, if it expires, or if it is
>     evicted to recover memory

Answer (score 5):

I've had the exact same error:

```
    Source: System.Runtime.Caching
    Exception type: System.InvalidOperationException
    Message: The method has already been invoked, and can only be invoked once.
    Stacktrace:    at System.Runtime.Caching.ChangeMonitor.NotifyOnChanged(OnChangedCallback onChangedCallback)
                   at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheEntry.CallNotifyOnChanged()
                   at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStore.AddToCache(MemoryCacheEntry entry)
                   at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStore.Set(MemoryCacheKey key, MemoryCacheEntry entry)
                   at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Set(String key, Object value, CacheItemPolicy policy, String regionName)
```

I've searched for it for hours.. until the light of logic struck me:

I was using a static policy object that was reused..  (some unconscious process in me reuses all objects if they are equal,maybe I am afraid of constructing objects that consume some bytes in memory )

By creating a new policy object for every item in the cache, the error was gone.   Pretty logical if you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a late answer as I've just faced the same issue and conducted my own investigation.

When you register your change monitor with a cached item policy —  `policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(cm)` — the `CacheItemPolicy` implementation registers its own change callback on it via `ChangeMonitor.NotifyOnChanged`. You're not supposed to be calling `cm.NotifyOnChanged` to register yet another callback, or it will throw `The method has already been invoked, and can only be invoked once` at that point.

Instead, use `CacheItemPolicy.UpdateCallback` or `CacheItemPolicy.RemovedCallback` to update/remove the cache item, e.g. as described in [this blog post](http://pdalinis.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/auto-refresh-caching-for-net-using.html).